# Will 2013 composed looks migrate to 2016?

Tags: 2013, 2016, migration, branding, composed-looks

If we are using the "database attach" method of migrating sites from 2013 to 2016, will the composed looks / branding migrate over easily?  Or are there any incompatibilities we will need to look out for?  Our "custom" masterpages are based on `seattle.master`, and don't really have anything removed, just some extra stuff added (like links to custom CSS files, loading jQuery, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

That is a hard one to answer, but if you are only loading custom CSS and some jquery then it should carry over ok, as long as best practices were followed.  Really with a migration you have to run a test to find all the issues.